# BackOffice module configuration CSS

Tags: css, module, prestashop

I want to use own css styles in BackOffice module configuration page, but I can't solve this problem, i want to use this code for insert CSS.

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'/css/styles.css', 'all');
```

Thanks for you help, and sorry for my English :)

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Answer (score 4):

for add css or js in backoffice first you should instal backOfficeHeader and displayBackOfficeHeader
in  install() function :

```
     public function install() {
          return parent::install() && 
         $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader')
            && $this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader')
    ;
}
```

then you can use them to add css :

```
 public function hookBackOfficeHeader($params) {       
      $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'mycss.css');
  }

 public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader($params){
      $this->hookBackOfficeHeader($params);    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way, but the syntax is :

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS($this->getPathUri().'views/css/styles.css', 'all');
```

where your css file is in $WEBSITE/modules/yourmodule/views/css/styles.css